# Can I "cache" an embedded MySQL select used several times?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-6

Working in Drupal 6, PHP 5.3, and MySQL, I'm building a query that looks roughly like this:

```
SELECT val from table [and some other tables joined in below]
    where [a bunch of clauses, including getting all the tables joined up]
        and ('foo' not in (select ...))
        and (('bar' in (select...) and x = y)
             or ('baz' in (select ...) and p = q))
```

That's not a great representation of what I'm trying to do, but hopefully it will be enough.  The point is that, in the middle of the query there is an embedded SELECT that is used a number of times.  It's always the same.  It's not completely self-contained -- it relies on a value pulled from one of the tables at the top level of the query.

I'm feeling a little guilty/unclean for just repeating the query every time it's needed, but I don't see any other way to compute the value once and reuse it as needed. Since it refers to the value from a top level table, I can't compute it once outside the query and just insert the value into the query, either through a MySQL variable or by monkeying around with the query string. Or, so I think, anyway.

Is there anything I can do about this?  Or, maybe it's a non-issue from a performance perspective: the code might be nasty, but parhaps MySQL is smart enough to cache the value itself and avoid executing the query over and over again?  Any advice?  Thanks!

Comment: Why not turn that test in to a function call? `FoundInTable('foo') AND NOT FoundInTable('bar') AND FoundInTable('baz')`?

Comment: From the description it looks like you're having a dependent subquery. Bad news: not really good for your performance (which you're probably seeing). Good news: in most cases it can be rewritten to a `JOIN` which is much faster. WE'd need to see some more details though.

Comment: Thx to both.  @BradChristie: I'm in Drupal 6, which is hanstringing me regarding stored procedures (my first thought, but D6 doesn't support them without hacking core to use mysqli).  Mchi: You're right on both accounts; I'll think about doing it as a monster join.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to alias the result by doing `SELECT ... AS alias`, and then using `in alias` in the other queries, since the `SELECT` is really just a table.

Comment: Hmm. I tried this, but it's failing.  This will probably be unreadable as a comment, but, with a simplified case like ---(('Nobody' not in (select pval.value as THE_ALIAS from profile_values pval, profile_fields pfields
  where pfields.fid = pval.fid
   and pfields.name = 'foo'
   and pval.uid = cc.uid))
 and (('Anybody' in THE_ALIAS)
      or ('Any_Member' in THE_ALIAS))---
I get a syntax error at the first "'Anybody' in THE_ALIAS" part.  (cc.uid is a table/value joined up earlier in the query.)  Any thoughts?

Comment: Instead of that, make a temporary table in a prior query - `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE the_alias SELECT ...`

Comment: yeah, I was thinking about that.  I'll give it a try.